# pycharm won't let me run from desktop

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been using pycharm for a while now, and I have to say that I am a real fan of it's features. I have one issue though, when I try to run a .py file from either the desktop or command prompt, I am instead prompted to use the run feature in pycharm. I consider this an issue because if I try to create a program for someone who doesn't know how to code, they would probably be scared off by opening pycharm. I don't, however, want to uninstall pycharm because it is so useful when writing code. Does anyone have any Ideas for me? By the way, I am using a dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming laptop with the current version of Windows 10 installed.

Comment: What is your actual question? What do you want to happen when you click on a .py file?

Comment: Note that file associations (i.e., the default thing that happens when you double-click on a file in Windows) are configured per-user. Your associations won't affect other users. Though if you want other people to be able to use your Python code they'll need to have Python installed, or you'll need to package your code for them, e.g. using something like py2exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running the direct path of the file, I'm not sure what you have tried.

If you wanted to run it as I just described you would do:

py C:\~AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\hello.py

If you move the file into your current working directory when programming, you should just be able to run py hello.py.

Comment: Are you sure that this answers the question? It looks like the OP is worried that their `.py` file association to PyCharm will affect other users.

Comment: You're right, I just reread his question and my answer literally makes no sense. Just wanted 15 points so I could vote on stuff.

Comment: I empathize. It's not that long ago that I was just getting started here myself. You'll get over that hump soon—just take an extra couple of seconds to make sure you're answering the right question :-).